# Copy Paste Range in Excel VBA error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with 5 columns (B to F) and a variable number of filled rows.
I want to copy the last 3 filled cells to a fixed range on the same column starting on row 101.

This the code I'm using:

```
Dim WSPL As Worksheet
 For i = 2 To 6
        For j = 7 To 1 Step -1
            If Not IsEmpty(WSPL.Cells(j, i).Value) Then
                WSPL.Range(Cells(j - 2, i), Cells(j, i)).Copy Destination:=WSPL.Cells(101, i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

This is returning error:

```
Run-time error: 1004
Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed
```

On line 5 of my code above. 
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: where do you `set` your WSPL ?

Comment: I set it before the loop above, like: Set WSPL = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Comment: @NunoNogueira you're looping backward from 7 to 1 , so when your `j = 2` the expression `j-2` in the loop evaluates to `0` which causes the error. Cant access row or column with an index of 0

Comment: @mehow that could be the case but I know that j is never < 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

`WSPL.Range(Cells(j - 2, i), Cells(j, i)).Copy Destination:=WSPL.Cells(101, i)`

Your cells object is not fully qualified

Try this

```
With WSPL
    .Range(.Cells(j - 2, i), .Cells(j, i)).Copy Destination:=.Cells(101, i)
End With
```

Notice the DOTs before Cells?

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem, although I don't understand why the dots before the Cells

Comment: @NunoNogueira When you don't put the dots, the cells will refer to the activesheet but you want to work with the `WSPL` and not activesheet :)